# Python ORM that auto-generates/updates tables and uses SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, auto-generate

I am doing some prototyping for a new desktop app i am writing in Python, and i want to use SQLite and an ORM to store data.

My question is, are there any ORM libraries that support auto-generating/updating the database schema and work with SQLite?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575172/portable-non-relational-database

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is a great choice in the Python ORM space that supports SQLite.

Comment: And you can migrate to another DBMS easily.

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy, when used with the [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/) library.