# Is there a not-relational database for python?

Tags: python, database, sparql, triplestore, non-relational-database

I am searching something like sqlite but not-relational. In other words I would like to work with a triple-store (a set of object-predicate-subject triplets) instead of tables. It means that I want to use SPARQL queries instead of SQL.

The first idea that comes into mind is RDFLib. However, I see two problems with this option:

1. RDFLib is not a data base and, as a consequence, it is not designed to work with parallel process (for example with parallel request induced by many web-users). It might lead to inconsistencies if two users at the same time try to add to or delete from the triple-store.
2. RDFLib is designed to work with RDF, which is a particular implementation (syntax) of the triple-store. For example, each object, predicate and subject have to have URI and I do not have them. In my triple-store I would like to have triplets like that: `("Washington","is capital of", "USA")` (so, no URI).

Comment: Is there not a MongoDB driver for Python?

Comment: you mean like http://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/? or http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/ ? or http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?  or ...

Comment: @DavidO: MongoDB isn't embedded, and it's a document store, not a ontology store.

Comment: This is off-topic.  From the close reasons: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPARQL is explicitly for RDF; if you want to use it you'll need to create your own ontology or utilise existing ones.

I recommend taking a look at [ORDF](http://ordf.org/) with [4store](http://4store.org/) as the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters already said, there is a wrapper interface for SPARQL - the SPARQL Endpoint interface to Python (currently in version 1.6.0): 
http://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/

I also came across another thread discussing non-relational databases with Python, although it doesn't specifically mention SPARQL: [portable non-relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575172/portable-non-relational-database)

While it doesn't have a whole lot to it, this guide for Python SPARQL developers has some pointers: http://www.openlinksw.com/blog/~kidehen/?id=1651